# Use Wifi IP instead of 3G IP Android

Tags: android, ip, wifi, 3g

I've got local wireless network with no internet access, and I use static IP of my router to connect from Android device. When 3G(HSPDA disabled) Android phone see and connect to the router in WiFi network (ssh), however when I turn on 3g, my phone cannot see WiFi router. Is there any workarounds for that without disabling 3G service while using local WiFi in app?

Comment: you looking to do this programatically, or just via a toggle in a setup menu or something? programatically would be a on-topic, but the other one just "how do I use my phone", which is off-topic.

Comment: @Marc B I am looking to do this programmatically without prompting user to disable 3G.

Comment: A wifi connection would normally take precedence over any mobile carrier, so there must be something more going on here...

Comment: @IMSoP Yes it is pretty strange for me too, I suspect it is happening because my WiFi hotspot has no internet access and then 3G IP allocation takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be suffering from an Android optimization. Try to go to the WiFi settings, hit the menu key and choose "Advanced", and uncheck "Avoid poor connections".

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46513/avoided-poor-internet-connection-even-though-signal-strength-speed-is-great

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not my case. That trigger is in off state on my device.